# Securing multiple routes with a shared parameter in Nancy Routing

Tags: nancy

I have a nancy module with multiple routes and want to do a security check on a parameter that is shared by each of the routes. Can I somehow move this parameter 'up in the hierachy' and have the check be a single line?

Example provided below

```
public SomeModule()
    {
        //ABC
        Get["/prefix/{someSharedParameter}/ABC/{noneSharedParameterA}"] = parameters =>
        {
            this.RequiresSomethingArbitrary(parameters.someSharedParameter);
            ...
        };

        //XYZ
        Get["/prefix/{someSharedParameter}/XYZ/{noneSharedParameterX}"] = parameters =>
        {
            this.RequiresSomethingArbitrary(parameters.someSharedParameter);
            ...
        };

    }
```

So I would like to be able to put the check `RequiresSomethingArbitrary` on module level here but not sure how or if that is even possible.

EDIT: I had an idea after finding out module base path but it came short.
THIS DOES NOT WORK. Context is null.

```
public SomeModule(): base("/prefix/{someSharedParameter}")
    {
        this.RequiresSomethingArbitrary(Context.Parameters.someSharedParameter);
        //ABC
        Get["/ABC/{noneSharedParameterA}"] = parameters =>
        {

            ...
        };

        //XYZ
        Get["/XYZ/{noneSharedParameterX}"] = parameters =>
        {
            ...
        };

    }
```

I also tried only doing the check if context is null because I figured it might be failing on initializing the module only but this will just always skip the check:

```
public SomeModule(): base("/prefix/{someSharedParameter}")
    {
        if (Context != null) {
            //this is unreachable (?)
            this.RequiresSomethingArbitrary(Context.Parameters.someSharedParameter);
        }
        //ABC
        Get["/ABC/{noneSharedParameterA}"] = parameters =>
        {
```

Comment: Did you even try it?

Comment: @tomredfern I had no idea what to even look for when I posted the question. Since then I found it's possible to have a base path in a module, which gave me an idea that didn't end up working. I had an idea this morning that I will be trying now. I will update my question with what I tried but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
public SomeModule(){
this.RequiresSomethingArbitrary(someSharedParameter);

 //route definitions go here

}
```

All you need to do is move the check to the constructor.

Comment: That doesn't compile because `someSharedParameter` is not defined in that scope. I'll update my example where I had a minor shortcut on why it is defined in route defenition scope

Comment: Ya well that will not work because it depends on `context` which is null until you get a request.Maybe its time to rethink your design.